# how to make a sharepoint form and connect it to azure devops (visual studio)

Tags: sharepoint-online, form, azure-devops

I would like to make a form of some sort in SharePoint so users can report bugs which will then be sent directly to our backlog in Azure DevOps (visual studio).

Could anybody tell me how I can make this connection in SharePoint as I haven't found any information about this online, maybe my google skills aren't great I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use SharePoint directly, consider using a Microsoft Form. You can embed the Form on a SharePoint page, if you wish.

From there, you can connect to the Form using Power Automate and create a flow to pass the responses from the Form to Azure DevOps into your backlog.

Comment: +1 for "don't use SharePoint unless you really have to"  XD